Can I make AccordionSummary into a box instead of fill the row
Here is my codesandbox I'm using Accordion component from MUI, if it's expanded, the content is displayed. I wanted to make the clickable "Status" like a small box (as imagine below/red box) and when it's expanded, the full content is displayed/fill the row. I'm having a hard time to make the AccordionSummary section into a box
Full working example code is in the sandbox.
If it's collapsed I just want the firs small box to be displayed.


I'm not sure. I thought Accordion is easier since it has the expand functionality. So you think create Box with expand functionality(another box?)

Yeah I have been trying to make the Status row smaller like button but I'm having a hard time to do it. Any ideas what property should I change?

I updated the sandbox code to make the Status looks like a button, still not sure how to shrink/cut off the rest of the row.

In style of AccordionWithBorder, add line this. margin: 0 auto;, width: 10%;, &:has(.Mui-expanded) {width: 100%;}. I'm not good at English, so I'm not sure what you want, but.. It will change width When Accordion expanded

Thanks, it did most of I want. Only thing left is can I keep the Status square in the same size(%10) when it's expanded? Basically keep the collapsed %10 and when the sub-item %100 when it's expanded?

That's why I asked you first. If you separate the status button, you won't get that problem. I'm glad you're close to what you want.

Thanks, is there a easy way to do it with my current code or I have to separate the status button to accomplish what I wanted?

I worked around the issue by change the background color. Thanks! @NINE
